# RAM dump analysis to locate application specific passwords for password protected files

Tags: zip, ram, dump, password-recovery, computer-forensics

For example, a password protected zip file.

If the user had opened it, entered the password whilst the computer was on, and then a RAM dump was taken, how would one go about finding where that password is located in the RAM dump?

I have attempted using a hex editor and searching the plain text of the password (I do know it as this is for learning purposes), but cannot locate it.

Would anyone be able to provide some guidance/resources on how one would go about approaching this problem?

Answer (score 0):

This is not so simple as you think (i suggest) ...
The Problem is, that the dump / the structure belongs to your operating system ... so you can use the recommended "programm/script" [volatility](https://github.com/volatilityfoundation/volatility/wiki/Command-Reference) to "render" your dump into a readable format.

When you have done, look at the task the volatility offers, and find what you are looking for ...